# Spring boot - Grabbing a file from the file system in a Get Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to grab a file (in this case an image) from the file system and display it.  I can do it from a resources subdirectory just fine, but when I try to go to the file system it is giving me a FileNotFound exception.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\Y:\Kevin\downloads\pic_mountain.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

All the rest of my code is vanilla spring boot that was generated from the Initialize.  Thanks.

```
@RestController
public class ImageProducerController {

    @GetMapping("/get-text")
    public @ResponseBody String getText() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/get-jpg", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public void getImage(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        FileSystemResource imgFile = new FileSystemResource("file:///Y:/Kevin/downloads/pic_mountain.jpg");
//        ClassPathResource imgFile = new ClassPathResource("images/pic_mountain.jpg");
        System.out.println(imgFile.getURL());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        StreamUtils.copy(imgFile.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to access filesystem like this??

Comment: You do realize that this code will never run outside your PC, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html):

```
public FileSystemResource(String path)
Create a new FileSystemResource from a file path
```

the constructor expects a path-part of the url, so in your case only `Y:/Kevin/downloads/pic_mountain.jpg`

so you should try to use it this way:

```
FileSystemResource imgFile = new FileSystemResource("Y:/Kevin/downloads/pic_mountain.jpg");
```

Btw. could it be, that you miss "Users" in your path? -> `Y:/Users/Kevin/downloads/pic_mountain.jpg`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. All the examples I saw had the "file:" part in front of it. I can stop beating my head against the wall now.